# Symfony 2 class table inheritance fixture SQL error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.2

I'm new here and quite new to symfony 2.

I try to build an Entity 'MailProcess' that inherits from an Entity 'Process'. Here are my Entity definitions:

```
// src/MW/TodoBundle/Entity/Process.php
namespace MW\TodoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity 
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="process_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"mailprocess" = "MailProcess", "process" = "Process"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="process")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks 
 */
class Process
{

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string") 
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime") 
     */
    protected $created;



    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type ="text", nullable= true)
     */
    protected $comment;
    protected $options;

    // Getters and Setters
}

// src/MW/TodoBundle/Entity/MailProcess.php
namespace MW\TodoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use MW\TodoBundle\Entity\Process;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="process_mailprocess")
 */
class MailProcess extends Process
{

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string") 
     */
    protected $from;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string") 
     */
    protected $to;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true) 
     */
    protected $subject;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true) 
     */
    protected $message;
}
```

You can see the ORM Class Table Inheritance used: Two tables 'process' and 'process_mailprocess' with discriminator column 'process_type'.

I do use 
    ´php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force´
to update the schema to my MySQL database which works fine.

But then there are my Data fixtures: I've stripped them down to one here, but be assured I have additional fixtures also testing the Entity 'Process' which are working fine.

```
// src/MW/TodoBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/ProcessFixtures.php

namespace MW\TodoBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use MW\TodoBundle\Entity\Process;
use MW\TodoBundle\Entity\MailProcess;

class ProcessFixtures implements FixtureInterface
{

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $mp1= new MailProcess();
        $mp1->setTitle("Invoice from heaven")
            ->setComment("sitebot: Irgendwer will was von euch!")
            ->setCreated(new \DateTime())
            ->setFrom("m")
            ->setTo("m")
            ->setSubject("m")
            ->setMessage("m");
        $manager->persist($mp1);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Alas, execution of
    ´php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load´
confirming 'y' to purge gets me

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO process_mailprocess (id, from, to, subject, message) VALUES (?,
  ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params {"1":28,"2":"m","3":"m","4":"m","5":"m"}:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your   SQL syntax; check the manual that
   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, subject, message) VALUES ('28
  ', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm')' at line 1






  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, subject, message) VALUES ('28
  ', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm')' at line 1
```

I can see nothing wrong there, and besides, Doctrine and Symfony create the SQL query.
Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong here? This is a real head-scratcher for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get a syntax error because `from` is a reserved word in MySql. You can set the column name in your annotation and quote it properly.

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="`from`") 
 */
protected $from;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are indeed correct. In combination with escaping the reserved `TO` this works correctly as expected.